# Collapse summary block in visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, summary, code-folding

I have been asking Mr Google about how I shall do if I want my  block to be collapse but not the code block. I write my code in C#.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, just click on the tiny `-` in the left margin on the same line as the first line of the summary. Or while having the cursor in the summary, hold the `Ctrl` key and press the `M` key twice.